# Web Service Handler class difficulties

Tags: json, swift, web-services, asynchronous

I hate to even do this as there is so much great content out there but I've hunted and hunted and I'm struggling to find good examples of separating a web service handler from creating the model. Basically I have in place a class that has functions to prepare the HTTP request, make the HTTP request, then parse the JSON object and make it into a NS Dictionary.  Unfortunately I am getting nils from the JSON object due apparently to the nature of my completion handler for makeRequest().  I'm still really new to swift, callbacks, and communicating with APIs in general.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import Foundation

class JSONService
{
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    var url : NSURL;
    var requestARGs : NSString;

    var request : NSMutableURLRequest!;
    //var response : NSHTTPURLResponse;
    var JSONdata : NSData!;

    var ModelFromJSON : NSDictionary!;

    //var responseString : NSString = ""

    init(URL : NSURL, ReqARGs : NSString)
    {
        url = URL
        requestARGs = ReqARGs;

        request = setupRequest(url, RequestARGs:requestARGs)

        makeRequest() {
            (response) in
            if let responseData = response as? NSData {
                self.JSONdata = responseData
            }
        }

        returnModel(JSONdata)

    }

    func setupRequest(URL: NSURL, RequestARGs: NSString) -> NSMutableURLRequest {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = RequestARGs
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return request
        }

    func makeRequest(completion: (NSData) -> ()) {
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(self.request) { data, response, error in
            self.JSONdata = data
            guard error == nil && data != nil
                else {
                // Networking Error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("Network Error, the Status Code is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            completion(data!)
            //self.JSONdata = data;
            //self.responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            //print("responseString = \(self.responseString)")
        }.resume()

    }

    func returnModel(data : NSData?) {

        if let responseData = data {
            do {
                let json = try
                    NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                                                           options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                print(json)

                if let dict = json as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                {
                    self.ModelFromJSON = dict
                }

            } catch {
                print("Could not serial data")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help on this matter!